# How long should data be stored in Redis Cache?

Tags: caching, memory, redis, stackexchange.redis

I know I'm sure this answer will vary greatly depending on business needs, but any insights on this? If my main purpose to use Redis Cache is for a fast in memory data storage and retrieval, should I set the expiry time for data to be 10 minutes? 15 minutes? 1 hour? 1 day?

Answer (score 1):

Probably for as long as it doesn't get stale? Sometimes it's set to minutes, hours or even days.

However, if this means that your cache will just start filling up and hitting memory limits, then you might experience other issues due to overhead with OOM errors, evictions, higher page faulting etc.

So how long data stays in the cache will likely need to be a balance between ensuring that your cache has up-to-date data but at the same time always leaves some room and generally tries to not run at full memory all the time.